# AngularJs to handle callback via POST method

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, angular, callback, http-status-code-405

We are integrating our Angular2 application with a 3rd party hosted payment solution. Per the requirement, we have to display the external credit card page within our iframe (per PCI compliance). Issue is, we are not able to handle the callback from the hosted payment solution. During callback, the current page is redirected to a blank page and displays “Cannot POST  /paymentlanding-page”.

On further analysis browser error says "405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed". and in Response Headers it shows "Allow: Get, Head, Options, Trace".

In our stringent requirement, had to solution this issue within Angular2 instead of having WebAPI or another application.

What would be the best approach to handle the callback from external service using POST method in AngularJs 2?

Any suggestions or recommendations will be of great support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http server you are using does not provide an endpoint  for /paymentlanding-page that can handle post requests. It can only handle get requests.

Depending on the web framework you are using you have to provide that endpoint.

Angular does not handle http requests sent to your application.

Comment: We are using .Net Framework & deploying this AngularJs in IIS. If we are providing a separate endpoint, then do you mean we need to write another application (eg: webapi or web application) to handle the call back requests?

Comment: No you should allready have a controller and action method  that serves the SPA html page (maybe HomeControlle / Index) . Add a second action method to the Controller for the landingpage that allows post requests by decoration it with the Post attribute

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, AngularJs is not constructed on MVC. Its a separate Ang2 application. That's the reason, I am thinking of creating a new MVC to handle callback.

Comment: Thanks. I added a API to handle the POST & sent back the data to Angular application as GET.

Comment: @SathishBalaiah: I am also facing the same issue. Can you please help me to get sample code to handle this scenario